# Assign true or false value one after another

Tags: java

I got a question from my assignment, I can't find a solution for this..

This array declares 12 variables..

```
boolean[] rowOfRotatoes = new boolean[12];
```

now I have to assign true and false value one after another,

```
rowOfRotatoes[0] = true;
rowOfRotatoes[1] = false;
rowOfRotatoes[2] = true;
rowOfRotatoes[3] = false;
rowOfRotatoes[4] = true;
....
rowOfRotatoes[9] = true;
rowOfRotatoes[10] = false;
rowOfRotatoes[11] = true;
```

but I have to use a loop to do this!

They have given me a structure to fill in blanks..

```
int plantingSpace = 0;
while(plantingSpace < 12) {

   rowOfRotatoes[plantingSpace] = <Fill this space 1> <Fill this space 2> <Fill this space 3> == 0;

   ++plantingSpace;
}
```

How to use above structure to assign true and false values one after another?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question `javascript`? I see nothing to do with Javascript in it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To strictly fill the spaces as your requirement dictates:

```
int plantingSpace = 0;
while (plantingSpace < 12) {  
   rowOfRotatoes[plantingSpace] = plantingSpace % 2 == 0;   
   ++plantingSpace;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo operator `%` to do this, by checking if the index is even. This will result in the right-hand side of the assignment alternating between `true` and `false`.

```
int plantingSpace = 0;
while(plantingSpace < 12) {
    rowOfRotatoes[plantingSpace] = plantingSpace % 2 == 0;
    ++plantingSpace;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a **toggling** boolean variable:

```
boolean[] rowOfRotatoes = new boolean[12];
int plantingSpace = 0;
boolean toggler = true;

while (plantingSpace < rowOfRotatoes.length) {
    rowOfRotatoes[plantingSpace++] = toggler;
    toggler = !toggler;
}
```

Denote that you can change the order of *true/false* entries by changing the initial value of the variable.

Comment: that is cool , very efficient

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `plantingSpace` is even or odd each loop and set your boolean true/false accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

easy kid... do like this

```
        Boolean rowOfRotatoes[]=new Boolean[13];
        int plantingSpace = 0;
        while(plantingSpace < 12) 
        {
           boolean value= (plantingSpace %2==0)?true:false; 
           rowOfRotatoes[plantingSpace] = value;

           ++plantingSpace;
        }
```

Here i used ternary operator , which check the condition and then according to it , it return false or true , then it gets into value.

> (plantingSpace %2==0)?true:false

Comment: I think you should think about what the statement `if <expr> then true else false` can be simplified to.

Comment: where i did if ??  :P

Comment: In your ternary statement.

Comment: why use if when we have ternary operator !!

Comment: I'll try again. `if <expr> then true else false` is the same thing as `<expr> ? true : false`, and they can both be simplified to just `<expr>`.

Comment: ok , gud thanks for telling me , i know already , the kid is not ready for this :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, starting with the first element of the array having `true` as value:

```
int plantingSpace = 0;
while(plantingSpace < 12) {
   rowOfRotatoes[plantingSpace] = (plantingSpace % 2 == 0);
   ++plantingSpace;
}
```

**Explanation:**

The expression `(plantingSpace % 2 == 0)` checks whether if the remainder of the division of `plantingSpace` by 2 (= modulo) equals zero.

If it is (meaning `plantingSpace` is even), the corresponding value in the array will be set to `true`.
If it isn't (meaning `plantingSpace` is uneven), the corresponding value will be set to `false`.